# How to reload just one loaded image in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, context-menu

I need to reload an image that comes in a page.
That image is loaded, and by <kbd>Right Click</kbd> I have just `View image` option.

Is there any way that I can have an option to reload the image in the context menu of image files in Firefox?

I'm especially interested in achieving this without using add-ons.

---

This feature is useful for me in this ways:

- By changing an image in the source path I can change the current showed image to the new image without refreshing whole the page.
- Sometimes I saw some images not showed and also are not broken.

Comment: As far as i know, Firefox shows reload image option in context menu if it detects that the image is incomplete or broken. Why do you need to reload a loaded image ? Which version of Firefox are you using ?

Comment: @vnodkumar1987 I want to reload an image that is already loaded ;).

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1052555

this is the closest that i have been able to reach about this and it also says "reload options is shown when the image is broken or incomplete"

Comment: @vnodkumar1987 Thanks for your time, I know it, and if there is not any way to reload an image, I should found an extension or an add-on ;).

Comment: Use Opera. It has a "Reload Image" function in the legacy version, and a plugin gives you the image reload function in its right-click context menu for the most modern version, whether the image is broken or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Image Context Menu** add-on:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-context-menu/

Comment: tnx (+1) for your answer, I'll try it, but my need does not fully covered ;).